# how to send video response to html player using node.js req.pipe(res)

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express

i am using ytdl-core to play a video. It plays the video.

here is code:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res)    
{    
var fs = require('fs');      
  var ytdl = require('ytdl-core');    
  req=ytdl;      
ytdl(Url)      
  .pipe(res);      
});
```

The output is same like when u open mp4 video from your pc with google chroome(openwith google chroome).

But i want to run this video in html or video js player which is placed in an html file.
Something like this

```
app.get('/',function(req,res)    
{    
var fs = require('fs');      
  var ytdl = require('ytdl-core');    
  req=ytdl;      
ytdl(Url)      
  .pipe(res.send("player.html"););      
});
```

But i don't know how to do this?How can i use the res to do this?
"player.html" source tag is some like this

```
<source src=Url type='video/mp4' />
```

SO, I want to send the coming response to html file(player.html) and want to show the video in html player or other compatible player which is in player.html file.How to set source tag in player.html? How can I do so? Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of setting video source is through the [video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) tag

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

It is advisable when using video (mp4) that you convert it to other formats (webm/ogg aswell) as fallbacks for media devices that don't play mp4s

Comment: you can put a file path where it says movie.mp4

Answer (score -1):

Send your html file through `/` url and load the video from a separate url. In second video url, just pipe the ytdl to response object.

**player.html**

```
<source src="/video" type="video/mp4">
```

**app.js**

```
//send page that loads your player
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/player.html')
});

//send your video through this url
app.get('/video',function(req, res) {
    var url = 'your youtube url';
    ytdl(url).pipe(res)
});
```